# Spring Boot @CrossOrigin annotation is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors

I have an Angular front end that is trying to call a spring boot API but the requests are being blocked due to CORS policy.

I followed [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) spring boot guide and ALL it says is to just add the `@CrossOrigin` annotation to the controller or method and it should work:

> This `@CrossOrigin` annotation enables cross-origin requests only for
>   this specific method. By default, its allows all origins, all headers,
>   the HTTP methods specified in the @RequestMapping annotation and a
>   maxAge of 30 minutes is used.

I put this annotation on my controller  class.

The `@RequestMapping` annotation is a POST request, and I'm calling exactly that, but I'm still getting this error:

> ...from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

It still doesn't work!

Why?

Comment: check the preflight body. Besides, what did you annotate? What request is beeing made?

Comment: @Antoniossss Annotated class with the annotation and am making a post request.

Comment: double check preflight response

Comment: I'm agree with @Antoniossss

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution @Kingamere

Comment: I just see that I was making HTTP requests to the wrong path.